# JQuery Knob Forwards and Backwards

Tags: jquery-knob

I have a JQuery knob that's displaying a value that can range from -5000 to 5000. I want it to have 0 be straight up, highlight going cw if the value is positive, highlight going ccw if the value is negative. Is there a simple way to do this with JQuery Knob?

Answer (score 0):

I have done your requirement with [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com) plugin, here you can completely customize this further. Check the below demo:

### [**`Demo -JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/135gh789/)

[image: roundSlider - zero at center, negative value at counter clock wise direction and positive value at clockwise direction]